# WPF Bind to array/collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have ~30 controls, each with the same model. I want, instead of having ~30 properties bound and ~30 private variables, to bind to an array, allowing me also to loop on the properties

For examle,

Say I have the following (It's just an example)

```
public class MyImage
{
    public String source { get; set;}
    public String tooltip { get; set;}
}
```

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Image Name="image0" Source="{Binding MyImage0.source"}/>
    <Image Name="image1" Source="{Binding MyImage1.source"}/>
    <Image Name="image2" Source="{Binding MyImage2.source"}/>
    ...
</Grid>
```

I want instaead of that `XAML` file, to have the source as something like `MyImages[0].source`
so I could also loop over it and set it in runtime and not have to write `MyImage0.source="mysource"`

Comment: consider using `ItemsControl` with `ItemsSource` set to collection of `MyImage` objects

Comment: But how would I then bind to it?

Comment: Can't MyImage0, MyImage1, MyImage2 be in a single collection of elements? If they are the same class, than it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

Having a Collection of Type MyImage like:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyImage> MyImageCollection { get; set; }
```

and then go with a DataTemplate and ItemsControl in your View:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyImageCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding source}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks,
I'll give it a try